# Compiling C programs with GLUT headers for Windows (in Linux)

Tags: c, linux, opengl, glut, cross-compiling

I can currently compile C programs with `stdio.h` and such like for Windows with the command `i586-mingw32msvc-gcc`, however I cannot do this for a GLUT program. When compiling it for Linux I use:

```
gcc main.c -lglut -lGLU
```

(I know, bad practice as it comes out with a.out)

Yet I am unsure of how I could do it for Windows using mingw32. When I run

```
i586-mingw32msvc -lglut -lGLU
```

it returns:

```
test.c:3:21: error: GL/glut.h: No such file or directory
```

The included header files are:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

And I am unsure of how to make it able to compile. Any ideas?

Comment: You should install the windows version of the library

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but how could I get this? I looked in Synaptic and could not see anything like that.

Comment: http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html

Comment: So I would get the zip file, extract it, and tell i586-mingw32msvc-gcc to link to that file? I will try it later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially that error tells you, that your MinGW GCC does not find the required headers. That is, because you're cross-compiling to another OS, and header files may contain OS specific things. Unfortunately OpenGL is one of those. So you have to install the required libraries in a Windows version as well.

However you should not just download some precompiled binaries from the web; you need libraries matching MinGW. You can of course install MinGW built libraries, that will work. However I suggest something different: Crosscompile and locally install all the libraries you require in your MinGW environment yourself. You do this, by passing the right compiler, linker and prefixes into the build configuration of each library. For example for autoconf based `configure` (on my system)

```
CC=i686-mingw32-gcc CXX=i686-mingw32-g++ ./configure --prefix=/usr/i686-mingw
```

`make ; make install` will then build and install the libraries and their headers in the MinGW environment, where you can use them as any other regular installed library.